# Forms Authentication Not Validating User properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms-authentication

I have this code when to sign in User , that string sUserData is properly set.

```
  Dim sUserData As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("UserID").Value & "|" & HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("UserName").Value & "|" & HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("UserEmail").Value

  Dim fat As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, _
     HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID"), DateTime.Now, _
     DateTime.Now.AddDays(6), True, sUserData, _
     FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)))
```

Then I have code where I check if the user if signed in in a Shared (static) method in a Public Class like this :

```
 If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
 EndIf
```

And that works just fine , but if I put the same line in Page_load instead of a Shared Method of a class it will never go into this If statement

```
  If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
  EndIf
```

Why is this happening , and is there some way to re-write this to work in the code-behind Page_Load instead of having to put it in a class ,The class is used in a header to allow access to certain pages - so that works fine.  But I need another way of authentication of user on Default page to change labels and buttons based on weather the user is logged in or not , and this   can not be done in a class.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're creating that cookie manually instead of using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`  Your code might work, but .NET will do it for you. (just an observation).

Comment: yes , there is  - it has to be like this ,  there are already 10k plus users , and my job is not to change all of it just make my code work with existing db

Comment: Aren't you trying to check the flag in the SAME request you create the cookie? This won't work, as the context will be set starting from a request next to the one you set the cookie.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - nah , if that was the case , then simply hitting refresh should make it work , because now its guarenteed to be checking after its been set , but it still doesn't work

Comment: Nope. Just hitting refresh sends the same request to the browser. It doesn't send the cookie if it was not present with the previous request. Anyway, use the http debugger to see if the cookie is there. Fiddler would be fine.

Comment: Cookie is there , its driving me crazy

Comment: Is your aspx file in another sub directory? If it is, is there another web.config there? Can you post your web.config authentication, authorization and location settings? When you debug, what's the value of `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the page event overrides into an actual page event override (i.e. OnLoad) instead of the Page_Load event hook implementation? More performant (fewer layers of invoke), slight difference in life-cycle which may suit your needs and may distill the cause of these symptoms.

There *may* be a sequencing issue / race condition if the context of the static method call and the Page_Load, I think Wiktor Zychla pointed you in the direction of fiddler already.

Comment: I figured it out , that was in the right direction - my sUserData was always correct, but I did not realize that is the session("UserID") was not set  then the whole authentication ticket does not get set , actually it does get set , but the value is empty